# Why is the data only displaying when it's in a foreach loop but outside it's a non-object?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and confused about this bit ..

When I have this it shows the data

```
<?php foreach ($profile as $p):?>
    <?php echo $profile->custom_url;?>
                    <?php endforeach?>
```

But when I do this I get " Trying to get property of non-object"

```
   <?php echo $profile->custom_url;?>
```

yet I have seen code where it's not in a foreach loop and the data displays. Can anybody help explain why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach should have the format of (array_expression as $value). [source](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php foreach ($profile as $p):?>
<?php echo $p->custom_url;?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: ok, but why doesn't <?php echo $profile->custom_url;?> work outside of the foreach?

Comment: What is $profile? An array? Do a var_dump($profile) and post that on here. Clearly it's not an object, PHP is telling you that. The foreach will work if $profile is an array of objects.

Comment: It is an array. Does this mean every time I see something like echo $profile->custom_url it was some how converted into an object?

Comment: You can convert an array to an object simply by saying
    (object)$profile

Answer (score 0):

```
// $profile is an array
<?php foreach ($profile as $profile):?>
    // inside foreach $profile is the element of the array $profile
    <?php echo $profile->custom_url;?>
<?php endforeach?>

// $profile is an array not an object
<?php echo $profile->custom_url;?>

// You'd better use another variable name for the element.
<?php foreach ($profile as $element):?>
    <?php echo $element->custom_url;?>
<?php endforeach?>
```